# i want data.js file to read data.js?key=123 as key = 123 inside its own code. so that the data.js file will work according to the key provided

Tags: javascript

I need help regarding getting value from javascript

i want to get key = 123 in data.js file so that i can send this value to another url.

same as google analytics get user id from url like

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-000000000-1"></script>
```

user id  = UA-000000000-1

i want data.js file to read key = 123 inside its own code. so that the data.js file will work according to the key provided

i want to use it as this, so that i can embed this code anywhere and it will start working, its same as other tracking sites provides code with userid

```
<script type="javascript" src="http://www.example.com/data.js?key=123"></script>
```

Comment: So have you tried anything?

Comment: Your title is confusing. Is the value _in_ the .js file somewhere, or are you trying to access a URL param?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but typically request parameters don't work with javascript files. They work with app engine (eg .php, .aspx, etc) files

Comment: i want data.js file to read key = 123 inside its own code. so that the data.js file will work according to the key provided

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 'data.js?key=123'; 
var b = a.substring(a.indexOf("?")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice(start,ends)` then put it in an object as key value.

```js
const url = "data.js?key=123"

const v = url.slice(url.indexOf("?") +1 ,url.length).split("=")

const [key,value] = v

console.log({[key]:value})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by enforcing some extra identifier to your script tag like `your library name` etc.

So that below code will fetch the queryParams based on the `src` attribute of your script tag. You can have this code in your `data.js` file.

```js
var scriptTag = document.querySelector("[data-script-id='my-lib-id']"); //getting your script tag based on your library id
var src = scriptTag.getAttribute("src"); //reading the script tag

var queryParams = src.slice(src.indexOf('?') + 1).split("="); //gets all query params from URL

console.log(queryParams);

var key = queryParams[1]; //index might change based on the  number of queryParams

console.log(key); //your key
```

```html
<script type="javascript" data-script-id="my-lib-id" src="http://www.example.com/data.js?key=123"></script>
```